# Can't connect to button in added view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

With this class I put a layout as a new page in a pageviewer.
That works fine, but now I want to put a listener to the button in the layout, but I can't find it.

```
public class questionListView extends LinearLayout {

public questionListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init();
}

public questionListView(Context context) {
    super(context);

     init();
}


private void init() {

    LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
    View myView = factory.inflate(R.layout.view1,null);

    LayoutParams params=new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    myView.setLayoutParams(params);

    addView(myView);

    Button btAddPhoto = (Button) myView.findViewById(R.layout.btAddPhoto);


}
```

}

btAddPhoto is not found in  R.layout.

Non of the controls in the layout view1 is accessable.

How do I have access to controls in a layout added as a view?

rg,
Eric

Comment: can we see the layout that's getting inflated?

Answer (score 2):

solved it.... its a button, so I should have used R.id.btAddPhoto instead of R.layout

I feel stupid now....

Comment: Don't worry; we all missed it too.

Answer (score 1):

Are you developing with eclipse? Some times the editor does't get it. So you may have to delete the R.java in the /gen folder and just compile it once again. When the eclipse generates the R.java it will find your R.layout.btAddPhoto id.

Comment: All the controls are in the R.java file. Did a clean anyway, but no change.

Answer (score 1):

If You have btAddPhoto.xml defined in a layout folder, then your IDE is not regenerating your R.java properly.  Clean your project and rebuild to resolve this (Project --> Clean in Eclipse)

Comment: If I open de R.java, I see the controls (buttons, textviews, etc.) in it. So it is generating it correctly.

Comment: Don't know if you resolved this.  But this sounds like perhaps you are importing the wrong R. check for import android.R; in your imports.